# Exchange Online - Task automation on behalf of other user

Tags: powershell, office365

I would like to run a one-off automated PowerShell task on my server but on behalf of other user/organization. For simplicity, this task should get list of inbound connectors (`Get-InboundConnector`).

```
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
# authentication step
Get-InboundConnector
```

As for authentication method, my thoughts is that I could use `Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device` ([Device Based Log-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps#device-based-log-in)) in my script, somehow parse the unique code and send it to the user, once he enters the code in his browser and approves, the script will resume running.

What are other possible authentication methods that could work in this situation?

Can I create a PowerShell application in Azure that requests from the user permission to manage his Exchange Online account and then ask him (thru UI) to grant this application the required permissions so it can be used to run the PowerShell script using access tokens & refresh tokens?

Few notes:

- Hardcoding user credentials is not an option (`Connect-ExchangeOnline -InlineCredential` is a no go)
- I don't want to ask the user to start configuring things on his end (should be as lazy as possible for him)
- REST API would be the best option (as far as I know it is not supported by Microsoft Graph)

Comment: Just noting that `Connect-ExchangeOnline -Device` is considered an interactive logon, and they go through a lot of trouble to make it so you can't capture the code. I believe they write that line directly to the console window so transcripts/audit logging etc don't see it.

Comment: You could try using OAuth tokens (app-only-authentication), though it takes some setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#setup-app-only-authentication

Comment: First of all, thank you for you reply.

As far as I understand, they saying: create an app, give the app permission, create a certificate and attach it to the app. 

Then, the app can authenticate with this certificate and do tasks on behalf of me. 
But this method won't work for other organizations wanting to use this app because delegation is not supported (as described in the green alert).

And in order to use "delegation", I have to become a "partner", and then I have to send an offer to my customers so they provide me with delegated permissions.